# Could you please translate below Latin?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

Translating this sentence to English.

Ipso die hoc idem donum confirmavit apud Saratam et filius ejus, Eubalus, laudavit; nec non et uxor ejus, Jordana, in manu Guidonis, prioris.

Could someone please translate this sentence in English please?

Thank you very much. Robert

Answer (score 4):

> On the same day he/she confirmed this same gift at Sarata, and his/her son, Eubalus, praised; and also his wife, Jordana, in the hand of Guido, prior.

The Latin is straightforward enough, but the antecedents are ambiguous and what it actually means depends heavily on the context. From a quick search I'm guessing Sarata is La Sarraz in Switzerland and Eubalus is Ebles III de Grandson, who was born there in the 12th century and seems to have been married to a Jordane. The use of *prior* as a title marks this as Medieval Latin.

Comment: Thank you very much. Robert